# Video slider/gallery on PHP (WordPress)

Tags: php, wordpress, video

I’m looking for help to create a video gallery for a WordPress page. I have the code that gets the videos URL from user generated content fields and displays it. Now I need to know if there is any script I can use to display multiple externally sourced videos as a slider.

```
<?php 
$video = get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_video', true ); 
$video2 = get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_video2', true ); 
$video3 = get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_video3', true ); 
$video4 = get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_video4', true ); 

if($video) : ?> 
<!-- Video -->

<div id="listing-video" class="listing-section">
    <h3 class="listing-desc-headline margin-top-60 margin-bottom-30"><?php esc_html_e('Video','listeo_core'); ?></h3>

    <div class="vc_row wpb_row vc_row-fluid">

        <div class="wpb_column vc_column_container vc_col-sm-6">

            <div class="vc_column-inner">

                <div class="wpb_wrapper">
                    <?php echo wp_oembed_get( $video, array( 'width' => 390 )); ?>
                    <?php echo wp_oembed_get( $video2, array( 'width' => 390 )); ?>
                </div>

            </div>

        </div>

        <div class="wpb_column vc_column_container vc_col-sm-6">

            <div class="vc_column-inner">

                <div class="wpb_wrapper">
                    <?php echo wp_oembed_get( $video3, array( 'width' => 390 )); ?>
                    <?php echo wp_oembed_get( $video4, array( 'width' => 390 )); ?>
                </div>

            </div>

        </div>

    </div>

</div>
<?php endif ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a TON of options out there for HTML sliders. Check out Ken Wheeler's [Slick.js](https://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/) Markup is flexible, it's well documented, and really easy to use.